# Pyspark Not Picking Up Custom Schema

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm testing this code.

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


customSchema = StructType([ \
StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
StructField("date", StringType(), True), \
etc., etc., etc.
StructField("filename", StringType(), True)])



fullPath = "path_and_credentials_here"
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', schema = customSchema, delimiter='|').load(fullPath).withColumn("filename",input_file_name())

df.show()
```

Now, my data is pipe-delimited, and the first row has some metadata, which is also pipe-delimited.  The strange thing is that the custom schema is actually being ignored.  Instead of my custom schema being applied, the metadata in the first row of the file is controlling the schema, and this is totally wrong.  Here is the view that I see.

```
+------------------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|               _c0|       _c1|         _c2|      _c3|            filename|
+------------------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
|                CP|  20190628|    22:41:58|   001586|   abfss://rawdat...|
|          asset_id|price_date|price_source|bid_value|   abfss://rawdat...|
|             2e58f|  20190628|         CPN|  108.375|   abfss://rawdat...|
|             2e58f|  20190628|         FNR|     null|   abfss://rawdat...|

etc., etc., etc.
```

How can I get the custom schema applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is because you're using the older (and no longer maintained) CSV reader. See the disclaimer note right under the title [of the package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

If you try the new format, it works:

```py
In [33]: !cat /tmp/data.csv
CP|12|12:13
a|b|c
10|12|13

In [34]: spark.read.csv(fullPath, header='false', schema = customSchema, sep='|').show()
+----+---+-----+
|name|foo|  bar|
+----+---+-----+
|  CP| 12|12:13|
|   a|  b|    c|
|  10| 12|   13|
+----+---+-----+
```

Comment: That works fine for showing the data.  Now, how do I load it into a dataframe?  I replaced the .show() with .load() and that didn't work.  I did some Googling too, of course, but didn't come up with anything that works for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @ASH the return value of `spark.read.csv(…)` _is_ a DataFrame. `.show()` is merely one of the methods you can call on the DataFrame. Store the return value of `spark.read.csv` in a variable.

Comment: I see.  Thanks so much!!